# Can't get polymer elements working in GWT

Tags: java, eclipse, gwt, vaadin, polymer-elements

I can't for the life of me get vaadin polymer elements working in a GWT project. I've got a new addition of Java EE Eclipse Mars, I'm using Gwt 2.8.0 SNAPSHOT beta, with updated Jars from Jan 11 from [sonatype](https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/google-snapshots/com/google/gwt/), I've got the `-generateJsInteropExports` tag set and I'm still getting the following jsinterop error. From what I can tell this should have been fixed in the latest beta but it doesn't seem to be working from me, and the nightly build didn't change anything. Any ideas?

```
Super Dev Mode starting up
workDir: C:\Users\John\AppData\Local\Temp\gwt-codeserver- 700489888360387855.tmp
Loading inherited module 'com.test.Gwttest'
   Loading inherited module 'com.google.gwt.core.Core'
     Loading inherited module 'jsinterop.annotations.Annotations'
        [ERROR] Unable to find 'jsinterop/annotations/Annotations.gwt.xml' on your classpath; could be a typo, or maybe you forgot to include a classpath entry for source?
```

Comment: You say you "updated Jars from Jan 11 from sonatype", which I understand as "not using Maven" (or Gradle, or any other dependency manager). Did you download com.google.jsinterop:jsinterop-annotations?

Comment: no not using maven, I don't see a download in sonatype for that, do you have a link to where that is at?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the `jsinterop-annotations` JAR and sources JAR too. Download them from https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/google-snapshots/com/google/jsinterop/jsinterop-annotations/1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/ (files ending with `.jar` and `-sources.jar`, e.g. [`jsinterop-annotations-1.0.0-20160111.054530-32.jar`](https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/google-snapshots/com/google/jsinterop/jsinterop-annotations/1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/jsinterop-annotations-1.0.0-20160111.054530-32.jar) and [`jsinterop-annotations-1.0.0-20160111.054530-32-sources.jar`](https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/google-snapshots/com/google/jsinterop/jsinterop-annotations/1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/jsinterop-annotations-1.0.0-20160111.054530-32-sources.jar))

Comment: thanks for this. After I included them it threw an error for asm, and had to download and include that as well. After that it seems to work.